# How to render UV sphere with edges?

Tags: uv

Hi I want to render something similar to this image. The below image should be my starting point.I used a UV sphere and I tried freestyle rendering but it is not showing the edges like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

Give your sphere a *Wireframe* modifier. Play with the parameters, disable the *Replace Original* option so that it keeps the whole sphere shape, make sure that *Material Offset* is set to the material slot the wireframe is supposed to display, i.e. *Material Offset* > 1 for the second material in the object's material list. In the Material panel prepare the materials, choose *Emission* type if you don't want any shadow.

[image]